# Authorize Attribute Still Passes As Successful Even If User Isn't Logged In

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, asp.net-identity

Good Day,
I'm stumped as to why even though I use the [Authorize] attribute on my controllers, it doesn't check to see if a user is logged in and still passes as an Authorization success. I am following the basic Identity and Authorization tutorials from Microsoft, [HERE](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authentication/scaffold-identity?view=aspnetcore-3.0&tabs=visual-studio) and [HERE](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authorization/simple?view=aspnetcore-3.0). I was able to get basic authentication up, creating a user and logging in and all that, but the authorization just allows guest to pass through and the system falsely recognizes them as successful. I used chrome to test, so i even used private mode and cleared the cookies and cache in the event the information was stored. I'm completely stumped, and I don't know what else to do.

Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authorization.DefaultAuthorizationService: Information: Authorization was successful.

Is the Authorization success message I get in the Debug console log.

Below is Startup.cs

```
 public class Startup
    {
        public Startup(IConfiguration configuration)
        {
            Configuration = configuration;
        }

        public IConfiguration Configuration { get; }

        // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to add services to the container.
        public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {
            services.Configure<CookiePolicyOptions>(options =>
            {
                // This lambda determines whether user consent for non-essential cookies is needed for a given request.
                options.CheckConsentNeeded = context => true;
                options.MinimumSameSitePolicy = SameSiteMode.None;
            });

            services.AddRazorPages();
            services.AddControllersWithViews();

            services.AddAuthorization(options =>
            {
                options.DefaultPolicy = new AuthorizationPolicyBuilder().RequireAuthenticatedUser().Build();

            });


            services.AddDbContext<DevContext>(options => options.UseSqlServer(Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection")));
            services.AddDbContext<UserContext>(options => options.UseSqlServer(Configuration.GetConnectionString("UserContextConnection")));
            services.AddIdentity<User, IdentityRole>().AddEntityFrameworkStores<UserContext>().AddDefaultTokenProviders();
            services.AddAuthentication(IISDefaults.AuthenticationScheme);




            services.ConfigureApplicationCookie(options =>
            {
                //Cokie Settings
                options.Cookie.HttpOnly = true;
                options.ExpireTimeSpan = TimeSpan.FromDays(150);
                //If the LoginPath isn't set, ASP.NET Core defaults the path to Account/Login.
                // options.LoginPath = "/Account/Login";
                // options.AccessDeniedPath = "/Account/AccessDenied";
                options.LoginPath = $"/Identity/Account/Login";
                options.LogoutPath = $"/Identity/Account/Logout";
                options.AccessDeniedPath = $"/Identity/Account/AccessDenied";
                options.SlidingExpiration = true;
            });

           // services.AddSingleton<IEmailSender, EmailSender> ();
        }

        // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to configure the HTTP request pipeline.
        public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
        {
            if (env.IsDevelopment())
            {
                app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
                app.UseDatabaseErrorPage();
            }
            else
            {
                app.UseExceptionHandler("/Home/Error");
                app.UseHsts();
            }

            app.UseHttpsRedirection();
            app.UseStaticFiles();
            app.UseRouting();
            app.UseCookiePolicy();
            app.UseAuthentication();
            app.UseAuthorization();


            app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
            {
                endpoints.MapRazorPages();
                endpoints.MapControllers();
                endpoints.MapControllerRoute("default", "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
                endpoints.MapDefaultControllerRoute().RequireAuthorization();
            }
            );


        }
    }
```

Below is the User.cs, left it blank because the basic demo didn't have any custom fields and it still worked. So I wasn't sure that would be the issue.

```
public class User : IdentityUser
    {

    }
```

And this is the Home Controller with the [Authorize] attributes

```
 public class HomeController : Controller
    {
        public IActionResult Index()
        {
            return View();
        }

        [Authorize]
        public IActionResult Information()
        {
            ViewData["Message"] = "Test Information Page";

            return View();
        }

        [Authorize]
        public IActionResult About()
        {
            ViewData["Message"] = "Your application description page.";

            return View();
        }
        [Authorize]
        public IActionResult Contact()
        {
            ViewData["Message"] = "Your contact page.";

            return View();
        }
        [Authorize]
        public IActionResult Privacy()
        {
            return View();
        }

        [ResponseCache(Duration = 0, Location = ResponseCacheLocation.None, NoStore = true)]
        public IActionResult Error()
        {
            return View(new ErrorViewModel { RequestId = Activity.Current?.Id ?? HttpContext.TraceIdentifier });
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your problem is this line:

`services.AddAuthentication(IISDefaults.AuthenticationScheme);`

This means your application will use your windows login to authenticate you and not the cookie you created.

I would change it to this since you are using a cookie based authentication scheme:

`services.AddAuthentication(CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
    .AddCookie();`

See guide below:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authentication/cookie?view=aspnetcore-3.0

I would also add functionality for creating and handling an antiforgery token to secure your application against cross-forgery.

**Update (Solution):**

This implementation is usign Identity which is already added so no need to call AddAuthentication()

Similar issue to this: github.com/aspnet/AspNetCore/issues/4656

Comment: Tried the change, and still no dice. Application still says the user is authorized even though the user isnt' logged in.

Comment: I see you are actually using Identity, then you dont need to use the AddAuthendication() at all as you already registered Identity, How do you sign in the users? See an example below: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authentication/identity?view=aspnetcore-3.0&tabs=visual-studio

Comment: I followed the instructions on that page, but I believe it was for 2.2 at the time. And I scaffold-ed and added Identity, placed it for Individual Accounts. Before I placed any authorized attributes I created a user using the provided Register function brought from Scaffolding. The test user logs in fine, but when trying to limit access with the authorize attribute, this is when the issue pops up.

Comment: Your issue sounds very similar to this: https://github.com/aspnet/AspNetCore/issues/4656 if that's the case it is indeed kind of a trap.

Comment: Thanks, I took a look at the link and that really seems to have been my issue. I tried what they did and it worked. Thanks again for your assistance, really appreciate it.